# How do I match on partial field matches in two R data sets using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, stringr

I have two data sets and I'm trying to create a data set based on a partial match of two fields from these two data sets.

I'm using `dplyr` filter and need to find partial partials in each row. I tried to use `str_replace()` but that doesn't seem to work on table$col.

Minimal reproducible example:

```
library(dplyr)

id <- c('1','2','3')
code<- c('a1231','b3211','c9871985')

tbl<- data.frame(id,code)

other_cd <- c('a123','b321','c987')
other_cd <- data.frame(other_cd)



match <- tbl %>% dplyr::filter(code %in% other_cd$other_cd) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(count = n_distinct(id))
```

Below is what I tried using str_replace()

```
fuzzy_match <- tbl %>% dplyr::filter(code %in% str_detect(other_cd$other_cd, "^[other_cd$other_cd]")) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(count = n_distinct(id))
```

I would like for `fuzzy_match`  to contain 3 rows with the partially matched items, so the output may look something like:

```
id        code      other_cd
1         a1231      a123
2         b3211      b321
3         c9871985   c987
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could `paste` the elements of 'other_cd' separated by `|` for matching any of the elements

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
tbl %>%
     filter(str_detect(code, str_c(other_cd$other_cd, collapse="|"))) %>%
      summarise(count = n_distinct(id))
```

#### Update

In the updated post, OP wants to create a new column from the other_cd.  In that case, we can use `str_extract`

```
tbl %>% 
   mutate(other_cd = str_extract(code, str_c(other_cd$other_cd, collapse="|")))
#   id     code other_cd
#1  1    a1231     a123
#2  2    b3211     b321
#3  3 c9871985     c987
```

---

Or if the number of rows are the same

```
tbl %>% 
    filter(str_detect(code, as.character(other_cd$other_cd)))
```

Comment: Thanks.  When I try the following:    `tbl$fm<- tbl %>% 
  filter(str_detect(code, as.character(other_cd$other_cd)))`    I am returning the longer code from `tbl$code`. What I want to return is the shorter code from  `other_code$other_code`

Comment: @Brad_J  I mentioned in the post that if you are doing comparison elementwise, you can use that, otherwise, do the `paste` approach i.e. first one

Comment: when I tried that the first one I got the same result.  I took the `summarise` out to make sure I am matching correctly using the following:  `tbl$fm2<- tbl %>%
  filter(str_detect(code, str_c(other_cd$other_cd, collapse="|")))` and I still just return `code`, not `other_cd`

Comment: @Brad_J What is your expected output

Comment: Sorry.  I edited my original question with a potential output.  In my toy example there would be a match on each but in reality there may not always be a match and that's ok - it would just default to NA.  Hope that helps